# Accesing objects in function($, window, document, undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

```
$(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "countdown360",
    defaults = {
      radius: 15.5,                    
      strokeStyle: "#477050",          
      strokeWidth: undefined,        
      fillStyle: "#8ac575",           
      fontColor: "#477050",            
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",       
      fontSize: undefined,            
      fontWeight: 700,                
      autostart: true,                 
      seconds: 100,                    
      label: ["percent", "percent"],    
      startOverAfterAdding: true,    
      smooth: true,                   
      onComplete: function () {}
};
```

Can you help me with how to access one of the properties in the object default please?

Comment: `defaults` is scoped to the IIFE. Unless it is returned ( exposed as a property ) you cannot access it.

Comment: Within your function you can access properties like so: `defaults.radius`

Comment: what if I want to access it outside of the function? what should i add to my code?

Comment: Add a breakpoint and access it via the web tools. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: can you help me explain further how to do access it by the web tools please @KevinB

Comment: @DuyHoang, where you want to access it from?

Comment: i want to access it from outside that function. For example, i'd like to change the fillStyle when a button is clicked.